# ASP.NET Server Control - How to add AssemblyInfo file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-3.5, custom-server-controls

I've noticed on a few tutorials online that when a new ASP.NET Server Control is added, it automatically includes Properties folder (containing AssemblyInfo.cs) and a References folder.

This works fine for me when creating a C# Server Control, but in VB.NET I just get a template .vb file and a Project file.

Why is this and how can I get an AssemblyInfo.vb file?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

AssemblyInfo.vb file is created for every project. By default it is not displayed in the Solution/Project Explorer.

To view this file and others in Visual Studio click **Project** >> **Show All Files** menu items.

Comment: Note that after clicking Show All Files, I found AssemblyInfo under the "My Project" folder